# Search Bar Does Not Display after Adding Table View Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am a beginner developer. I am trying to add a table view to a view controller that already contains a search bar. However, the search bar does not display after adding the table view. What could possibly be the issue?

[image: Here is the code I have so far.]

```
import UIKit

class SearchResultsViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    let reuseIdentifier = "ResultCell"
    var tableView = UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        title = "Search"
        
        configureTableView()
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    }
    
    func configureTableView() {
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        tableView.rowHeight = view.frame.height *  0.15
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

```
// MARK: - Search Bar Delegate

extension SearchResultsViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    
//    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
//        print(searchText)
//    }
    
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        print(searchBar.text!)
    }
    
}

extension SearchResultsViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please show us how you're showing the SearchResultsViewController?

Comment: Have you added a UINavigationController?

Answer (score 0):

You need to also add the `searchController.searchBar` to your parent view and add constraints to it.

> tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive =
> true

is telling your tableview view to be constrained to the top of the parent view and will ultimately hide your search bar.

Try something like:

```
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    view.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
    
    searchController.searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    searchController.searchBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    searchController.searchBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    searchController.searchBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    searchController.searchBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true //give it your own height

    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchController.searchBar.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the searchController in view and constraint

```
view.addSubview(searchController);
```